# How can I install Flash for Brave browser?

Tags: flash, browser

I installed [Brave](https://brave.com/) and it had no Flash. I went to the plugins and they were recommending a Flash version called PepperFlash. I found guides online and installed that version, but Flash is still not working in Brave. What should I do?

Comment: Close voters: This question is on topic, not off topic because Brave browser can be installed in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: I checked Brave browser for Flash video playback, and Brave browser does block all Flash videos possibly because of the built-in Brave script blocking feature's settings. My solution is to install Opera `sudo snap install opera` which also has a built-in ad blocker, but it plays all Flash videos by default. I think Opera web browser is what you're looking for even though it does not exactly answer this question.

Comment: I checked people's word on it in reddit and it seems that Opera was bought by a Chinese company and some woozy crap and I cant give my information to locals. It's also not open source so Idk. I was opting for Brave because it's kinda faster than a privacy configured firefox but meh

Answer (score 0):

I could make Flash work with Brave through these steps:

1. Installed Brave via the `.deb` file.
2. Installed the `adobe-flashplugin` package following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html#adobe-flashplugin).
3. Created symlinks so Brave finds the plugin:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree
   sudo ln -s ../adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so
   sudo ln -s ../adobe-flashplugin/manifest.json /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/manifest.json
   ```
4. Started Brave and enabled Adobe Flash support from *Settings -> Plugins*

*Edit:*

Hmm.. I was too quick. Even if I could enable Flash in the browser, the sites I tested with failed to read the plugin. Will revisit this attempt at an answer soon.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to revisit your answer?

Comment: @andrew.46: No. But since then the Flash infrastructure has been killed and Flash does no longer work with any browser.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone needs a flash browser in general, however I have tried a project that is currently being active in this github [repo](https://github.com/radubirsan/FlashBrowser) that works well on operating systems like Windows and Linux.